# Will OSX Server coordinate parental controls time limits across machines?

Tags: osx-server, parental-controls

I have kids with set daily time limits via Parental Controls (e.g. they can only use the computer for 2 hours a day during the week between certain times). At the moment, they have separate accounts on the different Macs in the house and thus inconsistent settings and time limits. If they use up time on one machine, they go to the next and get more.

If I used OSX Server and established their accounts as domain (?) accounts, would the time restrictions be coordinated across the machines? I would naturally assume that they would need to be actively on the network for the synchronization to work, but the idea being that if they use up 1 hour on one machine, they'd only have one hour left on the others as a result.

I haven't purchased or installed Server yet as it hasn't been compelling enough to do so, but not exactly keen on buying it to experiment :-)

Comment: I'm unable to comment, because of low reputation, but I have this question too. Been a few years since the first post, but would be interested to know if you found a solution to this? I'm going to try it with an old Mac mini,,, hoping to manage access by requiring traffic to go through the server first? I really have no idea what I'm talking about, but it would be a good evening project to learn to do it the better way

Comment: @woodstock I never found the answer to it myself, I just avoided the problem by limiting the accounts to just one machine.